# Nuget package dependency between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

Let's say that I have 2 class libraries.

I have included a NuGet package in project A. I need to instantiate classes from that package in project B.

Should I simply add references to the package by browsing from project A and point out the dll? Or is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same NuGet package in project B and use it.

Package manager in Visual Studio creates a directory inside your SoutionDir called "packages", it contains all NuGet dlls from all projects. So it does not download it 2 times...

Answer (score 0):

If you need classes from a package, add the package reference in project B through Nuget Package.

If you just need the classes from project A in project B, then add reference to project A from project B.

Comment: Wrong, you shouldn't reference Project A if the only reference your really need is in the NuGet Package. Reference the NuGet Package in Project B instead.

Comment: @phifi He said he needed classes from project A, so he must reference project A.

Comment: ok, maybe he is not clear enough in his question, but he wrote "I need to instantiate classes from that **PACKAGE**".